# Position fixed till before footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$(window).on("scroll",function(e){

var sidepos = parseFloat($('#footer').offset().top - $('#side').outerHeight());

if($(window).scrollTop() > 100 && $('#side').offset().top < sidepos) {
   $('#side').css('position','fixed');
   $('#side').css('top','0');
}

else if($(window).scrollTop() > 100 && $('#side').offset().top >= sidepos) {
     $('#side').css('position','absolute');
     $('#side').css('top','' + sidepos + 'px');
}

else if($(window).scrollTop() < 100) {
  $('#side').css('position','');
  $('#side').css('top','');
}

}); 
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="header"></div>
<div id="body">
     <div id="side"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to keep the `#side` fixed while scrolling till before the `#footer` so that it doesn't overlap with it.

Now there are 2 problems:

1. If you scroll down quickly like pressing 'end' button on keyboard, the function will not execute and the side overlaps with the `#footer` ignoring the if condition.
2. After switching to `position:absolute` can't figure out how to fix again when scrolling up and the `#side` becomes permanently sticking with the `#footer` even if you scroll up again.

I created a fiddle for you to test: http://jsfiddle.net/JuD5h/

Comment: Will this be a right summary of your requirement: The sidebar should always stay on the screen and never overlap with the header or the footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JuD5h/4/.

I made some changes to CSS:

```
#body {
    height: 3000px;
    position: relative;
}
#side {
    width: 100px;
    height: 350px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

And here is the updated Javascript:

```
$(function(){ // document ready
    var maxAbsoluteTop = $('#body').outerHeight() - $('#side').outerHeight();
    var minAbsoluteTop = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
      var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      var actualTop = windowTop - 100;
      if ( actualTop <= maxAbsoluteTop && actualTop >= minAbsoluteTop) {
          $('#side').css({ top: windowTop - 100 });
      } else if (actualTop > maxAbsoluteTop){
          $('#side').css({ top: maxAbsoluteTop });
      } else {
          $('#side').css({ top: minAbsoluteTop });
      }
    });
});
```

Use of `position: absolute` has made the animation flickery but I hope that is something you can fix using a small delay.

Comment: just checked...it overlaps with the footer...you just removed the part that prevents overlapping

Comment: ah, I have a bigger screen which didn't show the issue. I reduced the browser size and can see the issue now.

Comment: @MichaelSamuel - I have updated my code and checked on the smaller browser too. Please have a look.

Comment: just before reading your answer i have been able to get it to work by just checking for window scrolltop instead of side offsettop which would return inconsistent values if the element is fixed positioning...you can take a look here if interested http://jsfiddle.net/JuD5h/5/ Thanks for your effort :)